# Importing PsychoPy code (PsychoJS + ES6) to Gorilla (ES6)

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, gorilla, psychopy, es5-compatiblity

I'm working on creating an experiment for a psychology lab.
Both PsychoPy and Gorilla are software that utilise code and modular design to create experiments used particularly in a psychological context.

We would like to import an experiment built using PsychoPy into Gorilla in order to integrate it into our wider Gorilla project. For context, PsychoPy experiments use PsychoJS which is a JavaScript library, along with ES6 JavaScript. PsychoPy also produces “legacy-browser.js” files. On the Gorilla webpages they explain how to integrate jsPsych, but this is a JavaScript framework and is distinct to PsychoJS. Gorilla also currently runs on ES5 not ES6. Hence, we would very much appreciate any advice or guidance on how to achieve this.

We are trying to convert the ES6 code into ES5 code.

We are somewhat new to JS and Gorilla, so apologies if there is an obvious solution to this that we’ve missed. Looking forward to any ideas!

We have tried inputting PsychoPy code straight in; this doesn't seem to work, many errors pop up.